# Sort struct int members

Tags: c++

What would be a C++ way to sort `struct`s with different amount of integer members. (Notice they're always `int`s)

Suppose I have a struct with 3 `int`s in it and I want to sort them:

```
void Sort(int& x, int& y, int& z)
{
    //do stuff
    if(x > y >...etc) x = y z=tmp //etc etc
}

struct Foo
{
    int a {1};
    int b {3};
    int c {2};
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Sort(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c);
}
```

I could also pass `Foo` as an argument instead of 3 `int`s of course: `void Sort(Foo& foo)`

But suppose I have another struct with different amount of integers:

```
struct Bar
{
    int a{7};
    int b{8};
};
```

I would have to create another function for sorting:

```
void Sort(int& y, int& x) {}...
```

or even just for the struct `Bar` itself:

```
void Sort(Bar& bar) {};
```

Now, I've got many structs and all of them contain different amount of `int`s as data members. What is an overall way to sort the integer struct members in decreasing order?

-edit

I'll edit the question because maybe my fundamental approach to this is wrong.
In my original problem I have two structs:

```
struct PlayerPrince {
    int highCard;
    int middleCard;
};
struct PlayerPrincess {
    int highCard;
    int middleCard;
    int lowCard;
};
```

The values of the data members will be assigned accordingly to user input order. It can only be assured that `int highCard` will only be the highest card after the struct is sorted.

struct `PlayerPrince` does not need to have a `lowCard` and I would like to sort the members of each struct without defining multiple functions. If there is a better design approach to the problem (as stated in the comments) I'd be glad to know.

Comment: The overall way is (a) don't use individual members; use a container such as `std::vector` or `std::array` then (b) sort the container using `std::sort` . I don't understand the reason you're using individual members like `a`, `b`, etc, but this has all the qualities and distinct aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The standard prototype for a *compare* function to use with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) provided in `<algorithm>` is `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);` and makes sorting containers like `std::vector` on any member of the struct you like almost trivial. The *compare* function returns `true` if `a` sorts before `b` (no swap takes place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) in the comments, the key is not to declare individual integer values within your `struct` like `int a; int b; int c;`, but instead use a container such as [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (if you have a fixed number of `int` in that type struct), or use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (and add as many `int` values as you need to the vector)

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) provided by the `<algorithm>` header then makes sorting on `int` trivial as the default-compare function can be used without having to specify any special function of your own. Approaching the problem in this manner allows you to sort any number of integers contained withing your `std::array` or `std::vector` member regardless of how many integers are contained by using the standard `.begin()` and `.end()` iterators provided by the container.

**Using `std::array`**

For example, if you want to sort a struct with a fixed 3-integer array, you can simply do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo {    /* struct Foo with std::array<int, 3> instead of 3 int variables */
    std::array<int, 3> ints;
};

int main (void) {

    Foo foo;                    /* instance of foo */

    foo.ints.at(0) = 1;         /* add 3-int to array ints */
    foo.ints.at(1) = 3;
    foo.ints.at(2) = 2;

    /* sort foo.ints using default compare */
    std::sort (foo.ints.begin(), foo.ints.end());

    for (auto& i : foo.ints)    /* output sorted foo.ints */
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Using `std::vector`**

To use any number of integers in your struct simply replace `std::array` with `std::vector` and use `.push_back()` to add as many integers to your vector as you like. The case above becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo {    /* struct Foo with std::vector<int> instead of separate integers */
    std::vector<int> ints;
};

int main (void) {

    Foo foo;                    /* instance of foo */

    foo.ints.push_back(1);      /* add 3-int to vector ints */
    foo.ints.push_back(3);
    foo.ints.push_back(2);

    /* sort foo.ints using default compare */
    std::sort (foo.ints.begin(), foo.ints.end());

    for (auto& i : foo.ints)    /* output sorted foo.ints */
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** with `std::vector` you can add `1-integer` or `100000-integers` and the only thing that changes is the number of times you call `foo.ints.push_back(x);`)

**Using `std::greater<T>()` for Descending Sort**

The `<functional>` header provides several standard comparisons such as `std::greater<T>()`, `std::less<T>()`, `std::less_equal<T>()`, etc.. To sort the array or vector is descending our you can use `std::greater<int>()` as the compare function, e.g.

```
    /* sort foo.ints using std::greater<T>() compare */
    std::sort (foo.ints.begin(), foo.ints.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

**Example Use/Output**

In both cases using the default sort the output is the same:

```
$ ./bin/sortfooints
 1 2 3
```

(using `std::greater<int>()` would result in `3 2 1`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thankyou. `template<typename T, unsigned int N> struct Player { std::array<T,N> cards };` and then `std::sort(p.cards.begin(), p.cards.end(), std::greater<>());`did it